# <Image> source not working on binding

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to bind a listbox via ItemsTemplate to a collection of custom "Document" objects but am having an issue while trying to bind an image to the Document.ImageResourcePath property. Here is my markup

```
<ListBox Name="lbDocuments">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImageResourcePath}"
                                   Margin="5,0,5,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>                
</ListBox>
```

This is my load event for the form that has the listbox.

```
    private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        List<Objects.Document> docs = Objects.Document.FetchDocuments();
        lbDocuments.ItemsSource = docs;
    }
```

My Document class holds a string to a resource image located in my resources folder depending on the document extension.

e.g. (this is part of a case statement within the document class)

```
    case Cache.DocumentType.Pdf:
    this.ImageResourcePath = "/JuvenileOrganizationEmail;component/Resources/pdf_icon.jpg";
    break;
```

When the Window loads I get absolutely nothing in my listbox when it is bound to 23 perfectly well Document types. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Have you set your windows `DataContext` ?

Comment: For the purposes of debugging, try setting a fixed width and height on the images (in case they're rendering at zero size), and also add a TextBlock or similar to the StackPanel which is bound to the same field so you can see whether the correct data is being bound. Also check the Output window for binding errors.

Comment: @DavidCummins I just added a text block and it is popping up but the image still is not showing even with a hardcoded 20x20.

Comment: @sa_ddam213 I do not believe I have. I am not even sure what that is. I will google it now.

Comment: Okay, could you try hard-coding the Source to one of the values returned, so we can rule out whether the URI is just bad?

Comment: @Adrian, try adding `DataContext = this` above `List<Objects.Document> docs = Objects.Document.FetchDocuments();`

Comment: @DavidCummins hardcoding the source does indeed work along with the hardcoded 20x20. I also looked up datacontext and have set the listbox's datacontext to the List<Documents> that I am using to populate it and still no go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `ObservableCollection` instead of a `List`, and make the reference "class level" to your `Window`.

```
ObservableCollection<Objects.Document> _docs;
```

Make sure the DataContext is set in the Window's Ctor.

```
public Window()
{
  _docs = new ObservableCollection<Objects.Document>(Objects.Document.FetchDocuments());
   this.DataContext = this;
}
```

Then, you can just update your Window Loaded event:

```
   private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lbDocuments.ItemsSource = _docs;
    }
```

Or, an alternative solution, will be binding the ItemsSource of the ListBox directly to a public property of the collection. This is assuming the Ctor (above) is still used.

```
<ListBox Name="lbDocuments" ItemsSource={Binding Docs}>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImageResourcePath}" Margin="5,0,5,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>                
</ListBox>
```

In your Window.cpp file (though, a separate ViewModel class may be recommended if you are doing MVVM)

```
  public ObservableCollection<Objects.Document> Docs 
  {
     get { return _docs; }
  }
```

Comment: Problem solved. My issue was **this.DataContext = this** as opposed to what I was using. this.lbDocuments.DataContext = docs